# Heroku: cannot share httpOnly cookies between subdomains

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, cookies, fetch

I build the simple application that shows GitHub repositories. Here is the link for the app: https://wemake-services-test-client.herokuapp.com (firstly, you need to authenticate to GitHub). It seems to me that fetch doesn't send httpOnly cookies. Click "Sign In" and open the console:

[Console Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rBic.jpg)

Backend handler for route '/login' sets the httpOnly cookie:

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { createOAuthAppAuth } from '@octokit/auth-oauth-app';
import cookieOptions from '../cookieOptions';

export default async function login(req: Request, res: Response) {
  const code = req.query.code as string;

  const appAuth = createOAuthAppAuth({
    clientType: 'oauth-app',
    clientId: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_ID!,
    clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET!,
  });

  try {
    const userAuth = await appAuth({
      type: 'oauth-user',
      code,
    });

    const { token } = userAuth;

    res.cookie('ws_token', token, cookieOptions);

    res.json({ isAuthenticated: true });
    ...
```

Then I make GET to '/user' route which has the authMiddleware that checks if there is 'ws_token' in req.cookies and send status 401 (Unauthorized) if not.

authMiddleware.ts:

```
export default function authMiddleware(
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) {
  if (!req.cookies.ws_token) {
    res.sendStatus(401);
    return;
  }

  next();
}
```

So I got 401 error on '/user' because fetch doesn't send the httpOnly cookie `ws_token` from client side.

```
...
  async fetchUser(): Promise<GithubUser> {
    const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/user`, {
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
      },
      credentials: 'include',
    });

    const user: GithubUser = await response.json();

    return user;
  }
...
```

It works on localhost (without flag `secure` and `domain` set to localhost), but not on Heroku. But why? How to fix it?

Source code:

frontend – https://github.com/standbyoneself/ws-test-client (calls to API using fetch are in src/services/GithubService.ts)

backend – https://github.com/standbyoneself/ws-test-server

Answer (score 0):

Solved by disabling "Prevent cross-site tracking" in Safari Security Settings.